# Getting ERROR: WsTrust server returned error in RSTR: {'reason': 'MSIS7068: Access denied.', 'code': 'a:FailedAuthentication'} while connecting az

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-cli, non-interactive

I am trying to connect az by calling following command.

```
az login -u <username> -p <password>
```

*WsTrust server returned error in RSTR: {'reason': 'MSIS7068: Access denied.', 'code': 'a:FailedAuthentication'}*

Here we are getting errors as follow.

P:S: The user has no mfa and no conditional policies.I can able to login interactively.

Please help me to solve this.

Answer (score 0):

Please note that you cannot login through azure cli by providing **`Microsoft account credentials`** inside the command.

**I tried in my environment and got below results:**

Initially I tried with my **`Microsoft account`** and I got an error like below :

**Command:**

```
    az login -u <username> -p <password>
```

**Response:**

[image]

When I used **`Azure AD account`** I can login successfully.

**Command:**

```
 az login -u <username> -p <password> --allow-no-subscriptions --only-show-errors
```

**Response:**

[image]

Please check the similar kind of issue in [GitHub](https://github.com/Azure/azure-cli/issues/24102)  by yonzhan